# Issue declaring double two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am writing a program which lets the user put their own size of columns and rows for an array. I am using doubles so that the user can use decimals. However, I am getting this error that is telling me that I cannot convert doubles to integers. I don't understand why. I am using eclipse. I declare the array before the main method so I can use it freely the methods throughout the program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class array
{


private double themainarray[][];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private double columnsize;
private double rowsize;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.print("Welcome!");

    }


    //Below on the last line of the method is where I am getting the error from eclipse.


    public void arrayDimensions()
    {
        System.out.println("How many columns would you like?");
        columnsize = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How many rows would you like?");
        rowsize= input.nextDouble();
        themainarray= new double [rowsize][columnsize];


    }




}
```

Comment: The dimensions of an array can't be double. It must be int.

Comment: So I can declare a double array but the variables have to be int? That makes sense.

Comment: You can declare a double array that will contains double values, but the dimensions of the array have to be int. Arrays must be indexed by int values.

Comment: Look at it this way: I could declare an array of 2 doubles, or an array of 3 doubles, but what would it mean to have an array of 2.728 doubles?  If you agree this makes absolutely no sense, then you can see why your `rowsize` and `columnsize` have to be integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array size variables should be of type `int` only.Other are not allowed.

In your code `rowSize`,`columnSize` should be of type `int`.

Comment: I changed it, but now it's telling me that my array is not being used, am I changing the index correctly?

Comment: @munchschair now it is a warning not an error.You can now run it..or implement your remaining logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need an int for sizing an array.

```
private double themainarray[][];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private int columnsize;
private int rowsize;
```

Then when reading input from the user use nextInt();